# How to Export Crystal Report according to group and set File Name according to group

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report, desktop-application

I am working on a crystal report and displaying data according to groups. Now if I want to export specific group data and also assign file name automatically. for example: On report, I have different schools name and classes. So when I export the ABC school file and relatively classes information then the file name should be like ABC School Class currentDate.

Please advise if it possible in the crystal report to export 3 pages out of 48 according to the group and assign file name according to the field?

Answer (score 0):

There are several 3rd-party Crystal Reports automation tools (among those listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched)) that support multi-pass or single-pass report bursting (with dynamic export filenames).

You don't specify the runtime you wish to use but simple (multi-pass) approach is to restrict the data in the report using a parameter and record selection formula. Your code sets the parameter value, the desired export format, and the export file name. It then triggers the export via the runtime.

If you know your way around the runtime, this is fairly easy. If you don't, or if you need single-pass exporting with file name for each group value set dynamically based on data in the report, you may want to consider using one of the 3rd-party tools mentioned above.

Disclosure: I'm the developer of one of these 3rd-party tools.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but can you please explain in detail. I didn't find the exact or nearly solution to my problem.